# change iphone app "MinimumOSVersion" without xcode

Tags: iphone, minimumosversion

I have a custom app I have to test run.. But it doesnt work on my verizon iphone because in the info.plist file MinimumOSVersion is 4.3 when the verizon iphone goes up to 4.2.7.

Is there a way to edit this without xCode so I can use the app? I try to edit it then it wont let me add it into itunes. I have a pc and am using a plist editor to view the plist file in the .ipa file. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

I think when you are specifying deploy target something more then just a restriction for smaller versions is created. Something is changing in compilation process. So just changing a deploy target without rebuilding your app can cause troubles.

Comment: Good point. Can I do anything to edit it to work with my verizon iphone, or not really?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to do so without rebuilding your app with appropriate deploy target specified